# Xamarin.Forms How to put text/label over a BoxView element?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to achieve the result such as in the attached design sample below, I want to add the label SIGN UP and LOGIN over the blue and dark color BoxViews that I successfully created to match the design.

[image]

It seems that I cannot add  label into a BoxView in Xamarin.Forms so I would like to please know what is a good way to achieve this result.

Currently I am overlapping the BoxViews over the middle column.

```
 <Grid
        Margin="0"
        ColumnSpacing="0"
        RowSpacing="0"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--0 blank -->
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <!--1 logo -->
            <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
            <!--2 blank -->
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <!--3 main title-->
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <!--4 main title -->
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <!--5 main title-->
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <!--7 blank-->
            <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
            <!--8 subtitle-->
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <!--9 subtitle-->
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <!--10 blank-->
            <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
            <!--11 signup login bar-->
            <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
            <!--12 signup login bar-->
            <RowDefinition Height="7*" />


        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="65*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



        <Image Source="homePageLogo.png"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               HeightRequest="120"
               Aspect="AspectFit">

        </Image>

        <Label
            Text="{Binding MainTitle}"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.RowSpan="4"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            FontFamily="Gibson"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="50"
            LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
        </Label>


        <Label
            Text="{Binding SubTitle}"
            Grid.Row="8"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            FontFamily="Poppins"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="White"
            FontSize="Large"
            LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
        </Label>


        <!-- This is the boxview that should contain the LOGIN label -->
        <BoxView 
            Grid.Row="11"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            BackgroundColor="#2F3237">
        </BoxView>

        <!-- This is the boxview that should contain the SIGNUP label -->
        <BoxView 
            Grid.Row="11"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            BackgroundColor="#337EF3"
            CornerRadius="0,15,0,15">
        </BoxView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: just place the label in the same grid row/cell as the BoxView

Comment: @Jason I actually tried that but nothing shows up... unless the label sits behind the boxview, not sure how to "move to front" or "move to back" the layers, or how Xamarin decides whats in front if they occupy same cell.

Comment: elements that appear earlier in the XAML will be placed "under" elements that occur later

Comment: @Jason so I could declare the cell with the label first, Ok will give that a try, thanks for the tip.

Comment: no, if you want the Label on top of the BoxView it should appear AFTER the BoxView

Comment: Ok, noted thanks for correcting.

Comment: @Jason worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have solved this issue, please share your solution to answer and accept it, it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: @RazvanEmil Any update?